# Is there an easy rigging tool in blender?

Tags: animation, rigging

Good day.

I'm a software developer. I don't know how to animate but because of this pandemic i lost my job and i want to learn animation to be able to upload videos on youtube. I learn from doing things rather than reading or watching lengthy tutorials, then search a solution of error i encountered during the process.

Is there an easy rigging tool in blender? Something like. A tool that contain animations and we can also add custom animation. Then transfer the animation to our custom 3d model? Is there something like select the 3d model. click a button for animation then the animation will be applied to the 3d model?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, but there are two options:-

You can learn inverse kinematic(I am also learning that). It simplifies many things in rigging.

You can add the addon “Rigify” ( I hope I spelled it right). It adds premade skeleton in blender and you can dont have to install from some site. It lies in preferences.

Comment: yes i've read about it. which is better rigify or autorig pro? Thank you

Comment: Though auto rig pro is the no. one selling addon on blender market but it is of 40 dollars and rigify is free. As told you above it lies in preferences.

Comment: I think auto rig pro will be better